# What does this statement mean ? printf("[%.*s] ", (int) lengths[i],

Tags: c

I was reading this page 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-fetch-row.html
there is one line

```
printf("[%.*s] ", (int) lengths[i],
              row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");
```

from code

```
    MYSQL_ROW row;
unsigned int num_fields;
unsigned int i;

num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
{
   unsigned long *lengths;
   lengths = mysql_fetch_lengths(result);
   for(i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
   {
       printf("[%.*s] ", (int) lengths[i],
              row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");
   }
   printf("\n");
```

}

what does `[%.*s]` mean in that code ?

Comment: Which part of the man page confuses you?

Comment: only this code [%.*s] . what does it really doing ?

Comment: It does what the man page describes it as doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[%.*s]` is a `printf` format string meaning:

- the first argument should be an integer (specifying maximum length of a string to print).
- the second argument should be the string itself.
- the `[` and `]` (and trailing space) are transferred as-is.

Normally, you would see something like `.7s` which means a 7-character string. The use of `*` for the length means to take it from the argument given.

So what that entire line does is to print a string , the length of which is found in `lengths[i]`, and the value of which is `row[i]` (unless `row[i]` is NULL, in which case it uses the literal string `"NULL"`).

Answer (score 1):

`%.*s` is an output format string.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

```
printf("[%.*s] ", (int) lengths[i], row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");
```

Specifically in this case it means to print the the second argument (contents of `row[i]` or 'NULL' if contents of `row[i]` evaluate to false) with a maximum of `lengths[i]` characters.   The square brackets are not part of the formatting, they get printed themselves

Answer (score 0):

the `[%.*s]` part is a format string for printf.

it specifies that `printf()` should output a string (`row[i]`) but should limit the output to the length specified by a parameter (`length[i]`). the output string is enclosed inside square brackets.

see the [`printf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) documentation for more information on format strings.