# What does "%.*s" mean as a format specifier in printf?

Tags: c

Can anyone tell me what this means: `"%.*s"`

For example, it is in use here:

```
  sprintf(outv->deliveryAddressCity, 
          "%.*s",
          sizeof(outv->deliveryAddressCity)-1,
          mi->deliveryAddressCity);
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: I took the liberty to edit & put the parameters to sprintf on different lines since the code was not readable.

Comment: and your duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296123/what-does-this-statement-mean-printf-s-int-lengthsi

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the duplicate, that string is hard for google to search for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`%.*s` means *print the first X number of characters from the following buffer*. In this case, print the first `sizeof(outv->deliveryAddressCity) - 1` characters from `mi->deliveryAddressCity`, preventing writing beyond the bounds of `outv->deliveryAddressCity`.

A shorter example:

```
printf("%.*s", 4, "hello world");
```

would print `hell`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can get it with this example:

```
printf("%.*s", 3, "abcdef");
```

prints "abc".

Answer (score 2):

[`.*` The precision is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

So in your case the size of the string is `sizeof(outv->deliveryAddressCity     )-1`

Answer (score 1):

The width and precision formatting parameters may be omitted, or they can be a fixed number embedded in the format string, or passed as another function argument when indicated by an asterisk "*" in the format string. For example printf("%*d", 5, 10) will result in "   10" being printed, with a total width of 5 characters, and printf("%.*s", 3, "abcdef") will result in "abc" being printed.

(It was really easy to find it on a search engine...)

Answer (score 1):

It is most commonly used when you have a string that is not null terminated, and the length is stored elsewhere.

For example:

```
{
    char* regular_string = "Hello World";  // This string has a null-Terminator.

    char untermed_string[11];
    int len;

    // Specifically make untermed string so it is NOT null-terminated.
    memcpy(untermed_string, regular_string, 11);
    len = 11;

    printf("The string is %.*s\n", len, untermed_string); // This will still print the proper data!
    printf("The start of the string is %.*s\n", 5, untermed_string); // This will only print "Hello".
}
```

Comment: e.g. when intermixing C and Fortran, which whitespace-pads instead of null-terminates (yuck),

Answer (score 0):

this is a format-specifier, which takes 2 values from the stack, the first is the size, the second the value.

The .-notation: atleast-length.maxlength (so ".*" means: max * characters)

Answer (score 0):

it helps you to print the part of the string . u can specify to what length u have to print the string . example :  printf("%.*s", 5, ,"rahul subedi")
output:
rahul